# MySQL LEFT JOIN to consistently return data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

First of all, apologies for the wording of this question, 'cause it does seem rather inadequate to me.

I have three tables: `t1`, `t2` and `t3`. They all share a foreign key `id` that is also their primary key. I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3) ON (t1.id=t2.id AND t1.id=t3.id);
```

Naturally, the query returns empty when `t1` has no matching row, even if the other tables do. I cannot predict which table may or may not contain data, but I still want to return values (with `NULL`s for the non-matching tables). How can I do it?

I guess by the definition of LEFT JOIN, this is the expected behaviour. So, perhaps its another kind of JOIN that I should be using!

**EDIT**

```
t1

id    col1    col2
------------------

<EMPTY>


t2
-----
id    col3    col4
------------------
1     foo     bar
2     faa     boo
3     faz     baz    



t3
-----
id    col5    col6
------------------
3     hoo     har
4     haa     boo
```

When I do:

```
    SELECT * FROM t1 <WHATEVER JOIN> (t2, t3) ON (t1.id=t2.id AND t1.id=t3.id) WHERE id = 3;
```

I want to see something like:

```
id: NULL
col1: NULL
col2: NULL
col3: faz
col4: baz
col5: hoo
col6: har
```

Comment: The bigger question is: what do you want for output? If you want any commonality between the 3 then why not an implied JOIN with OR and all 3 permutations? (t1.id=t2.id or t1.id=t3.id or t2.id=t3.id)

Answer (score 0):

For the specific example that you provided, this query will get you the correct results:

```
SELECT t1.id as id,
       t1.col1 as col1,
       t1.col2 as col2, 
       b.col3 as col3, 
       b.col4 as col4,
       b.col5 as col5,
       b.col6 as col6
FROM t1 
RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT t2.id as id, 
       t2.col3 as col3, 
       t2.col4 as col4,
       t3.col5 as col5,
       t3.col6 as col6
FROM t2 
JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id) B
on t1.id = b.id;
```